# I want some Bones in my rig to stick to their relative position, so I can edit them better

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

So for example when I move an arm of my character and his hand moves relatively with him, everything is fine. When i want to change or turn the fingers though, the axis play against me. This is what I mean: [image]

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to accurately determine the meaning of your question, but the video helps.  I think you mean that the mesh that looks like a link-knob -- near one end of the bone -- seems to distort when the bone is rotated?

What may be necessary is for you to adjust the *weighting* of the vertices nearest the bone pivot end -- perhaps to the value of zero.

There are a couple of ways to do this...

METHOD 1: Weight Paint tool:

When you parented with Automatic Weights, blender would have created Vertex Groups that match the names of your bones.  Select the mesh and change from  the Object to *Weight Paint* mode, and you can paint a zero Weight (dark blue) onto the vertices you want to stabilize:

[image]

METHOD 2: select and adjust weights:

With the mesh in Edit mode, select a single vertex around the problem area.  You'll see the bone weights listed in table form:

[image]

Adjust downward (to zero?) this vertex you want to stabilize.  You can then use the Select box or Select circle or ctl-+ to add nearby vertices to the selected and use the Paste Weight to Selected (vertices) to adjust the whole group:

[image]

I don't show but you could pre-define you vertex "problem group" into a new vertex group (Assign to Group), so that you perhaps have less trial/error or increase your accuracy of selecting the "paste to" group.